# Need a default search engine for web browser control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have created a web browser app for windows phone 7 using web browser control. I want to add a default search engine(i.e, a textBox that is used for Google search or Bing search). And also if the user type anything(words like technology or so on), the search should be redirected to the above default search engine. Can anyone help me with this??? 
The textBox that I used for entering URL is named as "UrlTextBox" and my web browser control is named as "browsers". The textBox is used for search engine is named as "SearchTextBox".
Thanks in advance for your hard work!!!

```
    public void browsers_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        UrlTextBox.Text = e.Uri.ToString();
        if (navigationcancelled)
        { e.Cancel = true; }

        SearchEngine[] availableSearchEngines = new SearchEngine[]
        {new SearchEngine(){ Name = "Google", URLPattern = "http://www.google.com/search?q={0}" }};
         new SearchEngine(){ Name = "Yahoo", URLPattern = "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p={0}" };
         new SearchEngine(){ Name = "Bing", URLPattern = "http://www.bing.com/search?q={0}" };
    }
```

UrlTextBox-:

```
    private void UrlTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            Uri url;
            if (Uri.TryCreate(UrlTextBox.Text, UriKind.Absolute, out url))
            {
                this.urls[this.currentIndex] = UrlTextBox.Text;
                this.browsers[this.currentIndex].Navigate(url);
            }

            if (!Uri.TryCreate(UrlTextBox.Text, UriKind.Absolute, out url))
            {
                SearchEngine defaultSearchEngine = availableSeachEngines[0];
                String URL = String.Format(defaultSearchEngine.URLPattern, UrlTextBox.Text);
            }

            else
            {
                Navigate(UrlTextBox.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

But there is an error says **"availableSeachEngines"** --->
The name **availableSeachEngines** does not exist in the current context.

Now i have added my codes above that i have used in my program and also added Muaz Othman codes into it. But its not working for me and also shows the error. I think am making some mistakes in it. Can anyone correct it??? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a class like this:

```
public class SearchEngine {

    public string Name {set; get}
    public string URLPattern { get; set;}

    public override string ToString(){
        return Name;
    }
}
```

and in your code you can have this array:

```
SearchEngine[] availableSearchEngines = new SearchEngine[]{
    new SearchEngine(){ Name = "Google", URLPattern = "http://www.google.com/search?q={0}" };
    new SearchEngine(){ Name = "Yahoo", URLPattern = "http://search.yahoo.com/search?p={0}" };
    new SearchEngine(){ Name = "Bing", URLPattern = "http://www.bing.com/search?q={0}" };
}
```

but in your code you should have only one `SearchEngine` object:

```
SearchEngine defaultSearchEngine;
```

so when the user enters text and chooses "Go" you check if the entered text is a valid URL (maybe using a regular expression), and if not you do this:

```
String url = String.Format(defaultSearchEngine.URLPattern, SearchTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: Now i have created a SearchEngine class but i dont know where to put the second and fourth step codes. Can you help me with that? Sorry am new to c#!!! Thank you for your hard work!!!

Comment: Sure: the second part (the array) can be put in your `browsers` class as a data member, then you can type in the event of search button this code: `SearchEngine defaultSearchEngine = availableSearchEngines[0];
String url = String.Format(defaultSearchEngine.URLPattern, SearchTextBox.Text);`

Comment: It's not working for me Muaz, do you have any samples, so that i can understand easily!!!

Comment: Can you tell me how to integrate the search engine with the UrlTextBox, (i.e, when the user type simply a word) the page should navigate to google search???

Comment: Actually I am not using any external search button but am using the device keyboard's enter key as the search button.

Comment: Muaz Othman, now i have edited my question above with my codes used in my program and also added your codes into it. Can you please check it and correct my mistakes?

Comment: Sure you will get this error! you defined the array within the scope of a method, which is called "Local Variables", what you need is "Data Members". I mean you need to put the declaration `SearchEngine[] availableSearchEngines = new ....` outside the method so all methods can see it.

Comment: what is the class name in which you put these methods?

Comment: Let we assume that, i have created a web browser control named as "browsers" and a textbox for URL's. Now i don't want to create a search box seperately but i want to integrate the search engine inside the URL textBox. Now you please tell what to create or what to do? Need help please...

Comment: first of all you have an error in declaring the array, there are 2 braces after the first object, please make sure to write it properly, you can copy it from my code above. Second: just move the definition of the array outside the event. This should work just fine